# do something after a period of gui user inactivity tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

What is the general method for 'doing something' after a period of user inactivity in tkinter?  In my case the 'do something' will be to go to the start screen (tk.frame) that is already instantiated.

Comment: How do you define "inactivity"? Will any keypress or mouse click reset the timer?

Comment: Bryan, this is a touch screen user interface only, so in this case, if I've thought this through, I'm talking about mouse click.  Meaning the user just quit doing stuff.  Also, I don't know if it matters, but I have multiple screens instantiated, with just one of the screens shown at a time.  The screens are subclassed tk.frame classes.  So regardless of the screen shown, the timeout should work the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of looks something like this:

1. start a timer
2. set a binding on any key press or any button click to reset the timer
3. if the timer goes off, do something

### Create a function to call when the user is inactive:

```
def user_is_inactive():
    <your code here>
```

### Create a function to reset the timer.

We want to be able to call it from an event or directly, so the `event` argument needs to be optional:

```
timer = None
def reset_timer(event=None):
    global timer
    # cancel the previous event
    if timer is not None:
        root.after_cancel(timer)

    # create new timer
    timer = root.after(10000, user_is_inactive)
```

### Set up bindings to reset the timer

Using `bind_all` means that every widget can potentially handle these events:

```
root.bind_all('<Any-KeyPress>', reset_timer)
root.bind_all('<Any-ButtonPress>', reset_timer)
```

### Start the timer

A good time to do this is right before calling `mainloop`.

```
reset_timer()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, widgets (well event handlers) can stop event propagation, right? So in *theory* you may have a widget whose handler stops the event from triggering the reset. In those cases what I might do is create a decorator for the event handler called something like `reset_timer`.

Comment: @WayneWerner: yes, it's possible to have a widget that prevents events from being processed by other bind tags. It's somewhat unusual, and very easy to work around by creating your own bind tag, or by simply not preventing widgets from being handled from existing bind tags.

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you!  I don't have street cred to +1 your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I will admit that I have no experience in this, but maybe a sort of watchdog timer could work?  A timer would count up to your desired time, but anytime an element is activated it would reset the counter.  This concept is used in micro-controllers a lot but I'm not sure how you would apply it to python.